# UPDATE multiple rows in SQL from a list of IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I have a list of 200+ IDs (that a colleague made) and I need to change a column in each row. It's always the same column and the same value for each row. For example:

I have the table COMPANY(id, name, status) and a list of ID = 1,6,29,67,98,133, etc... For every ID I want to make the same UPDATE:

UPDATE COMPANY SET status="Clear" WHERE id= --LIST OF IDS--

And I would like to do it on phpMyAdmin directly. I searched everywhere and I don't find an answer! I hope that I'm not obligated to do it manually!
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?...)` for example